# Hyper-v 2012 R2 Nic Teaming with VLAN's

Tags: hyper-v, vlan, windows-server-2012-r2, network-teaming

Currently have a 3 node 2012r2 cluster.  Everything is working fine without any issues with networking / VLANS / etc...

The issue that I am having is needing to define the VLAN at the Guest VM Configuration Level.

I can create a Virtual Teamed NIC and assign it to say VLAN 13.  Attach the VirtualSwitch to this newly created Virtual Team.  However, no network connectivity.  I apply VLAN 13 to the Virtual Machine and this now works.

Let's take another approach.  I have my Teamed Nic "Team 1 - Core" and I create a virtual switch, assign the virtual switch to vlan 13.  This VM is not able to connect to items on that network.  I configure the VM to use VLAN 13, it will work.

I take the approach It's ignoring the Virtual Switch and the OS Teaming.  I apply VLAN 13 to both.  Same results.  I am required to assign VLAN 13 to the virtual machine and it works.

Ultimately, I do not want to manually assign the VLAN ID to the virtual machines.

edit: 
I have found the answer for this.

You *have* to do both.

1. Assign VLAN ID in the Team Interface 
   **OR**
2. Assign VLAN in Hyper-V vSwitch <- **Microsoft best practices** 
   **AND**
3. Assign the VLAN ID to the Virtual Machine

Comment: How do you have the physical switch configured?

Comment: The switches are Dell PowerConnect 8164 stack.  The port is in a Channel-group with switchport mode trunk. Allowing all vlans.  The only issue is when I do not define the Virtual Machine with the VLAN ID itself.  If I configure the vSwitch with the VLAN ID or the Team Interface with the VLAN ID it wouldn't work.

Comment: AFAIK, the VLAN setting on the vswitch is only for the communication from the HOST OS and has no influence on the guests. I'm still looking for a solution myself to make this work without VLAN configuration in the VM properties, but it looks like Hyper-V is just not able to do that :(

Answer (score 2):

Setup NIC Teaming, use this Virtual Adapter to setup a HyperV Virtual Switch and set the VLAN ID for the management OS on it. Set the VLAN ID of the VM on the network card of the VM.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/11/20/vlan-tricks-with-nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012.aspx